# Unexplained file NULL pointer for file that exists

Tags: c, linux, file-access

I have a file that exists in the same directory as my .c and my executable under Linux. 99 times out of 100 it will open the file correctly and not return a null pointer. But this 1 time out of 100 it will return a null pointer, the code is shown below. Why would I only sometimes get a null pointer for this file? And why when I do get the null pointer does it fail to create a file with the same name if Linux thinks it doesn't exist?

```
int ID_Lookup(int serialNumber, int NodeID)
{
    FILE *nodeidfile = NULL;
    char temp[8];
    char *filebuff;
    int commapos, endpos;
    int fileserialnum = 0, id = 9, match = 0, x = 0, linechar = 0, y;
    size_t len = 0;

    nodeidfile = fopen("NodeIDs","r");
    if (nodeidfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("file not found, creating it\r\n");
        nodeidfile = fopen("NodeIDs","w");
        fclose(nodeidfile);
    }

    nodeidfile = fopen("NodeIDs","r");

    if (nodeidfile == NULL)
        return -1;

    printf("file found\r\n");
    fseek(nodeidfile,0,SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(nodeidfile);
    fclose(nodeidfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error code to see what's going on?

Comment: yes, gdb says error with null pointer here:fclose(nodeidfile); inside the first if {}

Comment: @EoinOConnell *Checking the error code* means looking at the `errno` variable (for instance) to find the **reason** the open failed. We all accept that it is failing, it's the reason that is important.

Comment: ok errno gives me 24, too many open files, why is this happening?

Comment: Probably because you are opening files and not closing them? Not necessarily here. It might be somewhere else in the process.

Comment: `fopen("NodeIDs","r");` opens the file in *text* mode. That means [`ftell()` does not return an actual length value](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."  `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file is not conforming C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If fopen succeeds the first time, you open the file again (abandoning the first FILE* -- you're no longer able to close that first file). This system eventually runs out of file handles.

You should handle the two cases independently.

```c
int ID_Lookup(int serialNumber, int NodeID)
{
    FILE *nodeidfile = NULL;
    char temp[8];
    char *filebuff;
    int commapos, endpos;
    int fileserialnum = 0, id = 9, match = 0, x = 0, linechar = 0, y;
    size_t len = 0;

    nodeidfile = fopen("NodeIDs","r");
    if (nodeidfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("file not found, creating it\r\n");
        nodeidfile = fopen("NodeIDs","w");
        fclose(nodeidfile);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("file found\r\n");
    fseek(nodeidfile,0,SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(nodeidfile);
    fclose(nodeidfile);

    return 0; /* should return len? */
}
```

Comment: The file will have been opened in a different mode if it didn't exist. You could `fclose` it after creation and `fopen` it again with the correct mode, all within the `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, yep. I've edited the code to reflect that correction.